# Parsing error in a FileReader onload function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I am getting an error with my FileReader unload function. The error is `Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` I looked in to what that means to according to **MDN web docs: "invalid assignment left-hand side" occurs when there was an unexpected assignment somewhere. For example, a single "=" sign was used instead of "==" or "===".** I don't see how this would be a error.

```
 var fileInput = files[0];
 var audioCtx = new AudioContext(files[0]);
 var reader1 = new FileReader();
 reader1.onload() = function (ev) { //error here
     //decode audio
          audioCtx.decodeAudioData(ev.target.result).then(function(buffer) {
                reader1.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput.files[0]);
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onload` is a property, not a method.

```
reader1.onload = function (ev) { 
   ...
}
```